# Create Option Not Found in Jasper Server 4.5.0

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I want to create an Ad Hoc report in jasper server.
I am using Jasper Server 4.5.0 installed on my local machine.
I can see View and Manage options only.
Or, is there any way to create Ad Hoc reports in iReport 4.5.0 and I can run it on the jasper server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Create" menu is available only in commercial editions of JasperReports Server. (That includes Create Ad Hoc Report, Create Dashboard, Create Domain.)

With JasperReports Server Community Edition you can deploy and run and schedule any reports that you create in iReport.